# Jasmine: how to spy on inner object method call?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, bdd, jasmine

I have two prototypes I want to test:

```
var Person = function() {};

Person.prototype.pingChild = function(){
   var boy = new Child();
   boy.getAge();
}

var Child = function() {};

Child.prototype.getAge = function() {
    return 42;
};
```

What exactly I want to test: **to check that `getAge()` method is called inside of the `pingChild()` method**

That is Jasmine specs I try to use for this purpose:

```
describe("Person", function() {
    it("calls the getAge() function", function() {
        var fakePerson = new Person();
        var chi = new Child();
        spyOn(fakePerson, "getAge");
        fakePerson.pingChild();
        expect(chi.getAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

describe("Person", function() {
    it("calls the getAge() function", function() {
        var fakePerson = new Person();
        spyOn(fakePerson, "getAge");
        fakePerson.pingChild();
        expect(fakePerson.getAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});

describe("Person", function() {
    it("calls the getAge() function", function() {
        var fakePerson = new Person();
        var chi = new Child();
        spyOn(chi, "getAge");
        fakePerson.pingChild();
        expect(chi.getAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

but all of them shows just errors:

> - getAge() method does not exist
> - getAge() method does not exist
> - Expected spy getAge to have been called

***So, is there any way to test such cases using Jasmine, and if yes - how can it be done?***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have yo spy on the prototype of `Child` object.

```
describe("Person", function () {
  it("calls the getAge() function", function () {
    var spy = spyOn(Child.prototype, "getAge");
    var fakePerson = new Person();
    fakePerson.pingChild();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible because inner object is not accesible from outside the parent object. It's all about the scope of your objects.

You could either expose your `Child` object in `Person` object by doing this:

```
var Person = function() {
    this.boy = new Child();
};

Person.prototype.pingChild = function(){
   this.boy.getAge();
}
```

And then:

```
describe("Person", function() {
    it("calls the getAge() function", function() {
        var fakePerson = new Person();
        var chi = fakePerson.boy;
        spyOn(chi, "getAge");
        fakePerson.pingChild();
        expect(chi.getAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Or delegate the initialization of the `Child` outside the `Person` object:

```
var Person = function(child) {
    this.boy = child;
};

Person.prototype.pingChild = function(){
   this.boy.getAge();
}
```

And then:

```
describe("Person", function() {
    it("calls the getAge() function", function() {
        var chi = new Child();
        var fakePerson = new Person(chi);
        spyOn(chi, "getAge");
        fakePerson.pingChild();
        expect(chi.getAge).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```